# Passing multiple strings to a function and appending to list

Tags: python, class, oop, keyword-argument

```
class Dog:
   tricks = []
   def __init__(self,name):
     self.name=name
   def add_tricks(self, trick ):
     self.tricks.extend(trick)
```

I keep getting the error that add_tricks only accepts 1 positional arguments but 3 were given. I tried passing **kwargs to the function but that didn't work either. How do I pass multiple strings to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For (*args) parameters as ("Hello","Byy")`

```py
class Dog:
   tricks = []
   def __init__(self,name):
     self.name=name
   def add_tricks(self, *trick):
     self.tricks.extend(trick)
```

`For (**kwargs) parameters as (a="Hello",b="Byy")`

```py
class Dog:
   tricks = []
   def __init__(self,name):
     self.name=name
   def add_tricks(self, **trick):
     self.tricks.extend(trick.values())
```

`Or if you want to give string in both types like ("Hello",b="byy")`

```py
class Dog:
   tricks = []
   def __init__(self,name):
     self.name=name
   def add_tricks(self, *trick1,**trick2):
     self.tricks.extend(trick)
     self.tricks.extend(trick2)
```

Comment: So it works when I use the *args method but produces errors using **kwargs like in your second code. "add_tricks() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given"

Comment: `a = Dog("bruno")

a.add_tricks("fetch", "roll") ` This is what I am trying to add